# Azure SQL Database, NodeJS app: failed to connect

Tags: node.js, sql-server, database, azure

probably someone has encounterd the same problem and have a solution.

I have a SQL Database in my Azure Portal account. I have created a NodeJS application in a website, using CPanel > Setup NodeJS App funtionality.

Then I installed the mssql plugin for connecting a NodeJS app with an Azure SQL Database. This is my starting, connection code:

```
let sqlConfigTEST = {
    user: "my_user_name",
    password: "my_password",
    database: "my_db_name",
    server: "my_url_to.database.windows.net",
    port: 1433,
    pool: {
        max: 70,
        min: 0,
        idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
    },
    options: {
        encrypt: true,
        trustServerCertificate: false
    }
};

var myDB = new SQL.ConnectionPool(sqlConfigTEST, err => { if (err) { console.log(err); } else { console.log("OK"); } });
```

When I launch the app, the ConnectionPool() method rises this error:

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to my_url_tp.database.windows.net:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
> App 1801 output:     at /home/qgsqpvwr/nodevenv/dashboard/12/lib/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious/connection-pool.js:70:17
> . . . etc, etc . . .
> App 1801 output:     code: 'ESOCKET',
> App 1801 output:     isTransient: undefined

Basically, it's just the for some reason my app can't remotelly communicate with my Azure DB. The only thing I tryed is to add my website shared IP to the Azure Firewall rules, but it didn't worked.

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: `ESOCKET` seems like it could be a firewall issue. Can you `telnet my_url_to.database.windows.net 1433` from the CPanel host? Once the socket connects you might also have issues establishing a secure connection due to `trustServerCertificate: false`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use telnet because the hosting I have is just a "classic" hosting with no admin privileges. Another thing is that my SQL Server has the Connetion Policy opition set to Default. This piece of info is from MS doc: "The default policy is Redirect for all client connections originating inside of Azure and Proxy for all client connections originating outside". Maybe I have to configure mssql to use a proxy?